# How do I put an integer inside a byte array at a given location?

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I want to fill in a byte array with variables at given positions.

As a minimal example, below's code tries to insert an int variable at location 10 of a byte array (which would use bytes 10,11,12 and 13 of the byte array).

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

       // DESTIONATION BYTE ARRAY
       byte[] myByteArray = new byte[64];

       // INTEGER
       int myInt = 542323;

       // I WANT TO PUT myInt AT POSITION 10 IN myByteArray
       // PSEUDOCODE BELOW:
       myByteArray.putInt(myInt, 10);

     }
}
```

I am not sure which alternatives do I have to copy an int directly to a given location of a larger byte array.

Comment: Presumably you want the byte order to be the same as the native one?

Comment: As far as I know the byte order in Java is defined by the standard? So it is not like in C where byte order depends on the architecture?

Comment: That's true. Java uses big endian. But you might use a different byte order if you were, say, sending this data to a little endian device, right?

Comment: If I understood correctly how things work Java's big endian matches with network endinaness, which is my intention here (I intend to send the data via an UDP packet). Hence I do not need to use native order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), which already has the logic of splitting the int into 4 bytes baked in:

```
byte[] array = new byte[64];

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
// buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // uncomment if you want native byte order
buffer.putInt(542323);

System.arraycopy(buffer.array(), 0, array, 10, 4);
//                                         ^^
//                        change the 10 here to copy it somewhere else
```

Of course, this creates an extra byte array and byte buffer object, which could be avoided if you just use bit masks:

```
int x = 542323;
byte b1 = (x >> 24) & 0xff;
byte b2 = (x >> 16) & 0xff;
byte b3 = (x >> 8) & 0xff;
byte b4 = x & 0xff;

// or the other way around, depending on byte order 
array[10] = b4;
array[11] = b3;
array[12] = b2;
array[13] = b1;
```

Comment: From somewhere else I got  -related to this example-: `byte[] totalByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(this.total).array();` why `.array()` is used there but not in your example?

Comment: @M.E. I used `.array()` in my code as well. It's to get a `byte[]` from a `ByteBuffer`.